# Exportando dados para o Firebase

Tags: python, json, firebase, dicionário

Estou tentando exportar uma base de dados do Python para o Firebase.
Minha base de dados é um JSON no seguinte formato:

```
'{
   "0":{
         "country":"Italy",
         "description":"Aromas include tropical fruit, broom, brimstone and dried herb. The palate isn\'t overly expressive, offering unripened apple, citrus and dried sage alongside brisk acidity.",
         "designation":"Vulk\\u00e0 Bianco",
         "points":87,
         "price":null,
         "province":"Sicily & Sardinia",
         "region_1":"Etna",
         "region_2":null,
         "taster_name":"Kerin O\\u2019Keefe",
         "taster_twitter_handle":"@kerinokeefe",
         "title":"Nicosia 2013 Vulk\\u00e0 Bianco  (Etna)",
         "variety":"White Blend",
         "winery":"Nicosia"},
```

Estou criando nós como timestamp, e tentando importar apenas os primeiros 1000 valores do JSON para dentro dos nós utilizando a seguinte função:

```
i = 0

for key, wine in df.items():
    if i < 1000:
        id = int(time())
        db.child("wines").child(id).push(wine.val())
        i += 1
    else:
        break
```

Porém estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'val'

Alguém sabe qual a forma correta de chamar apenas os valores do dicionário?

Comment: Vc não deveria fazer o push de wine? Penso que `for key, wine (...)` vc terá a chave em `key` e o objeto do dicionário em `wine`.

Comment: Fiz conforme você comentou e retornou o seguinte erro: TypeError: Object of type Series is not JSON serializable

Comment: Já tentou assim: `db.child("wines").child(id).push(json.dumps(wine))`? Tem que importar a lib json antes: `import json`

Comment: Pessoal, consegui solucionar, transformei minha informação em um DataFrame do Pandas e apliquei o seguinte codigo:        
    id = int(time())+i
    wine = df.iloc[i]
    wine = wine.to_json()
    db.child("wines").child(id).push(wine)